# laravel vuejs and axios no data shows with auth user

Tags: php, vue.js, axios, laravel-6

No data shows when i add find(Auth::id())
But with find(1); data retrieves.

Axios script

```
export default {
  data () {
return {
 jobs: []
}
  },
mounted() {
    axios
  .get('/api/dashboard')
  .then(response => (this.jobs = response.data))
     },
}
```

api.php router

```
    Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function 
 (Request 
     $request) {
     return $request->user();
     });
    Route::resource('dashboard', 'HomeController');
```

Homecontroller

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
public function index(){
 return User::find(Auth::id());
}
```

No data shows when i add find(Auth::id())
But with find(1); data retrives.

Comment: Did you check dumping data of `Auth::id()`?

Comment: Yes By Dumping shows the user data! if access home page data shows there not showing only in vuewjs template

Comment: Well your `index()` method does not return anything. Try using `return User::find(Auth::id());`

Comment: Same issue! blank no data

Comment: Well what was that dumped data? Can you show us?

Comment: {"id":2,"name":"admin","email":"admin@admin.com","email_verified_at":null,"created_at":"2020-02-12 09:39:53","updated_at":"2020-02-12 09:39:53"}

Comment: Is it from `var_dump(Auth::id());`?

Comment: yes id is only 2 Auth::user() vardump gives full array of user.

Comment: I am not clear about your last question. Is the json data above from `var_dump(Auth::user());` or from `var_dump(Auth::id());`?

Comment: That is data if i access that route directly to web browser. like http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard

Comment: but i did check with var dump and data tributes are showing

Comment: Please be specific.

Comment: Data comes in Laravel with return  User::find(Auth::id());  and with this return  User::find(2); command. My issue is Data in my vuejs template using axios comes only with return  User::find(2) command. no data comes in vuejs template with return  User::find(Auth::id()) command. I just want to know if there is any issue with my api.php router or its in template? Thats why i have posted my full code in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using Auth::id(); ?

Try to use

```
User::find(Auth::user()->id);
```

Comment: Error reported on Console with no data!app.js:699 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 500

Comment: I just want to access the data of logged in user. User Profile page you can say to edit.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue! I think my api.php router having some issue I just switch router file from api.php to web.php and issue fixed. Thank you who took their time to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your **api.php** file is all fine. In your **kernel.php** file just look for this line **\Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class** and uncomment it, now you can use routes in your **api.php** to access **Auth**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).